# Angular.js error 404 routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a simple angular.js app with two views: /login & /register.
My index.html looks this way:

```
... 
<body>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-view></div>
...(javascript inclusions)...
```

**app.js**

```
var adventureApp = angular.module('ownAdventure', [
      'ngRoute',
      'ngCookies',
      'Login',
      'Register'
    ]);

adventureApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: '/login/login.view.html'
    })

    .when('/register', {
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        templateUrl: '/register/register.view.html'
    })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}]);
```

I've got both **Login** and **Register** modules in sepparate **.js** files, and added the *LoginController* and *RegisterController* accordingly in both files exactly the same.

**login.controller.js (same with register):**

```
'use strict';

var loginController = angular.module('Login', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

loginController.controller('LoginController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'This is a simple test';
}]);
```

Both **login/** and **register/** folders are inside the **app/** folder at the same level as **app.js**, therefore I cannot figure out why I constantly get the following error message:
GET http://localhost:8000/login/login.view.html 404 (Not Found)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what os are you working on? Is it case sensitivity?

Comment: I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04, but I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem, I've tested the angular-phonecat tutorial and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The error message : GET http://localhost:8000/login/login.view.html 404 (Not Found)" Implies that there is no login.view.html in the given folder hierarchy or it is not accessible at the given moment. As this error is related to your code, we will not bother about it. Coming to the folder hierarchy, what is your application name? (I believe it is "ownAdventure"). So the index.html page loads at "localhost:8080/ownAdventure/". You mentioned "Both login/ and register/ folders are inside the app/ folder at the same level as app.js" it doesn't help much, because you didn't mention the folder hierarchy for app.js. I assume that app.js is right under your app folder.

In that case "localhost:8080/ownAdventure/login/login.view.html" will be accessible.

Note:  "templateUrl: '/login/login.view.html'" the path provided here is relative to the parent path, not to the file from which it is called(in this case app.js).

Comment: My app name is 'ownAdventure', but that does not mean that the route is "localhost:8080/ownAdventure/". In angular-phonecat tutorial in angular.js official webpage you can see it. App module is 'phonecatApp' while the index route is 'http://localhost:8000/app/#/phones'.

On the other side, as you deduced I've got an **app/** folder and both **login/** and **register/** folders inside, at the same level as the **app.js** file.

Comment: Yeah your are right about the first part. Can you mention the index route? and I believe that you are unable to access **http://localhost:8000/login/login.view.html** from the browser

Comment: I am definitely surprised, as I assume the GET should be localhost:8000/app/login/login.view.html , but fails to retrieve it.
I don't know what you mean for index route.

Comment: anyway I figured the index route :). Now I got your actual concern!!! Why **"templateUrl: '/login/login.view.html'"** resulted in a get request for " localhost:8000/login/login.view.html " instead of "localhost:8000/app/login/login.view.html" am I correct?

Comment: Yep! I just figured it out too and was posting the answer! You got the credit though, It was hell of a concentration lapse.. thank you!

Comment: It happens a lot to me, while working on angularJs. I'm glad you figured it out.